# how to make a column in a datagrid with icons?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, icons, itemrenderer

I have a datagrid in the first column has two different values 0 and 1, I would like to change those values by icons (example: 0 = red icon, 1 = green icon).

I know I have to do with ItemRenderer, but I can not find any example.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex4_02.html) . Very detailed, you have to use 'Custom itemrenderer implementation' keyword to search in google.